# How to load animated GIF from URL in FLutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, gif

Here's my Flutter code to load one GIF in Android Studio:

```
Image.network(
                  'https://flutter-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/happy_mothers_Day.gif',
                  width: 300,
                  height: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                )
```

but I always get an error like this:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://flutter-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/happy_mothers_Day.gif
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://flutter-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/happy_mothers_Day.gif", scale: 1)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://flutter-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/happy_mothers_Day.gif", scale: 1)
====================================================================================================
```

Can anybody help me to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you testing this GIF? I mean web/ android...?

Comment: I'm testing Web by chrome

Comment: Provide render option, hope it will resolve, you can check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on web, providing render will solve this issue.

I'm running on chrome with html renderer
`flutter run -d c --web-renderer html`

does it solve in your case?

Comment: After updating path environment variable for Flutter SDK and then running "flutter run -d c --web-renderer html" in Android Studio's terminal, I finally can sucessfully load the GIF! Thank you very much for the help!